# pecl install mongodb fails: fatal error: 'Security/Security.h' file not found

Tags: mongodb, security, pecl

When I execute `pecl install mongodb`

The result is:

> ERROR: 'make' failed
>
> /private/tmp/pear/install/mongodb/src/libmongoc/src/libmongoc/src/mongoc/mongoc-rand-common-crypto.c:25:10: fatal error: 'Security/Security.h' file not found
>
> 1 error generated.
>
> make: *** [src/libmongoc/src/libmongoc/src/mongoc/mongoc-rand-common-crypto.lo] Error 1
>
> ERROR: `make' failed

I dont known how to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

Are you execute this command in macOS mojave?

I have the same situation before, I found solution [here](https://medium.com/@rossbulat/hi-corey-6f2ae707ba9d).

try execute this command first:

```
xcode-select --install
```

then execute:

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

then try execute `pecl install mongodb` again, it should be works.